# the splitting field of $x^3 - x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to figure out the splitting field of $x^3 - x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ .

I know $x^3 - x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ is irreducible because there are no root in  $\mathbb{F}_3$.

The spitting field will be the field $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^3 -x +1\rangle$（my intuition is that all roots are added to $\mathbb{F}_3$.）
So,the spitting field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3^3$.

> My question is ;
>
> How to formally prove that the spitting field is the field
> $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/\langle x^3 -x +1\rangle$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean $\Bbb F_{3^3}$, note that the product of fields is never a field

Comment: Hint: If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-x+1$ then so will be $\alpha+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix an algebraic closure an take $\omega$ a root of $f = X^3-X+1$ there. Since the Frobenius map is an automorphism, you can check that $\omega + i$ with $i \in \Bbb F_3$ are also roots of $f$.

Hence the splitting field of $f$ is $\Bbb F_3 (\omega)$, of degree $\deg f = 3$ over $\Bbb F_3$, and thus by uniqueness we get $\Bbb F_3(\omega) = \Bbb F_{3^3}$. Now, consider the ring map

$$
\Bbb F_3[X] \to \Bbb F_3(\omega)
$$

sending $X$ to $\omega$.

The kernel of the map is $(f)$. There are a couple of ways to see this but one is to note that $(f) \subset \ker \mathbf{ev}_\omega$ is a maximal ideal, and the kernel a proper submodule since since $X \mapsto \omega \neq 0$. Its
image is $\Bbb F_3[\omega]$, the smallest $\Bbb F_3$-algebra containing $\omega$, hence $\Bbb F_3[X]/(f) \simeq \Bbb F_3[\omega]$.

It is a general fact that if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$, then $k(\alpha) = k[\alpha]$. Namely, by the same argument as before one gets $k(\alpha) \supset k[\alpha] = k[X]/(m(\alpha,k))$, which is a field by the irreducibility of the minimal polynomial. Since this field contains $\alpha$, by definition of $k(\alpha)$ we have $k(\alpha) \subset k[\alpha]$, hence the equality.

Also, there's nothing special about $3$ here, it may very well be substituted for any prime $p$ to obtain that the splitting field of $X^p-X+1$ is $\Bbb F_{p^p}$.

Comment: Thank you ! Let all the root of f in algebraic closure of F3 be α1,α2,α3, then the spitting field is F3（α1,α2,α3）＝F３（α1）（This is a key）, and it is easy to show the proposition with evaluation map, right ?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb F_3(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3) = \Bbb F_3(\alpha_1)$ because $\alpha_2,\alpha_3 \in \Bbb F_3(\alpha_1)$. I've detailed the proof of the evaluation map inducing the desired isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry, but why α2,α3 ∈F3（α１）？

Comment: because they are $\alpha_1+1$ and $\alpha_1 +2$